# Reducing values in lists of (key, val) RDD's, given these lists are values in another list of (key, val) RDD's

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I've being rolling my head for a while over this - would really appreciate any suggestions!
Sorry for long title, I hope a short example I'll construct below will explain this much better.

Let's say we have an RDD of the below form:

```
data = sc.parallelize([(1,[('k1',4),('k2',3),('k1',2)]),\
           (2,[('k3',1),('k3',8),('k1',6)])])
data.collect()
```

Output:

```
[(1, [('k1', 4), ('k2', 3), ('k1', 2)]),
 (2, [('k3', 1), ('k3', 8), ('k1', 6)])]
```

I am looking to do the following with the deepest list of (key,val) RDD's

```
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
```

(i.e. reduce the values of these RDD's by key to get the sum by key while retaining the result mapped with keys of the initial higher level RDD, which would produce the following output):

```
[(1, [('k1', 6), ('k2', 3)]),
 (2, [('k3', 9), ('k1', 6)])]
```

I'm relatively new with PySpark and probably missing something basic here, but I've tried a lot of different approaches on this, but essentially cannot find a way to access and reduceByKey the (key,val) RDD's in a list, which is itself a value of another RDD.

Many thanks in advance!

Denys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is : your value (in input K,V) is an **iterable** on which you want to sum on inner key and return result as =>

(outer_key(**e.g 1,2**) -> List(Inner_Key(**E.g."K1","K2"**),Summed_value))

As you see the sum is calculated on **inner Key-V**, 
we can achieve this by

First **peeling out** elements from each list item

=> making a new key as (outer key ,inner key)

=> making a sum on (outer_key,inner_key) -> value

=> Changing data format back to (outer_key ->(inner_key, summed_value))

=> finally **Grouping** again on Outer Key

I am not sure about Python one but believe just replacing Scala collection syntax with python's would suffice and here is the solution

**SCALA VERSION**

```
scala> val keySeq = Seq((1,List(("K1",4),("K2",3),("K1",2))),
     | (2,List(("K3",1),("K3",8),("K1",6))))
keySeq: Seq[(Int, List[(String, Int)])] = List((1,List((K1,4), (K2,3), (K1,2))), (2,List((K3,1), (K3,8), (K1,6))))

scala> val inRdd = sc.parallelize(keySeq)
inRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, List[(String, Int)])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[111] at parallelize at <console>:26

scala> inRdd.take(10)
res64: Array[(Int, List[(String, Int)])] = Array((1,List((K1,4), (K2,3), (K1,2))), (2,List((K3,1), (K3,8), (K1,6))))


// And solution :
scala> inRdd.flatMap { case (i,l) => l.map(l => ((i,l._1),l._2)) }.reduceByKey(_+_).map(x => (x._1._1 ->(x._1._2,x._2))).groupByKey.map(x => (x._1,x._2.toList.sortBy(x =>x))).collect()

// RESULT ::
res65: Array[(Int, List[(String, Int)])] = Array((1,List((K1,6), (K2,3))), (2,List((K1,6), (K3,9))))
```

**UPDATE => Python Solution**

```
>>> data = sc.parallelize([(1,[('k1',4),('k2',3),('k1',2)]),\
...            (2,[('k3',1),('k3',8),('k1',6)])])
>>> data.collect()
[(1, [('k1', 4), ('k2', 3), ('k1', 2)]), (2, [('k3', 1), ('k3', 8), ('k1', 6)])]

# Similar operation

>>> data.flatMap(lambda x : [ ((x[0],y[0]),y[1]) for y in x[1]]).reduceByKey(lambda a,b : (a+b)).map(lambda x : [x[0][0],(x[0][1],x[1])]).groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect()

# RESULT 
[(1, [('k1', 6), ('k2', 3)]), (2, [('k3', 9), ('k1', 6)])]
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I am not quite familiar with Scala syntax to translate solution line to python, but the python syntax is materially different

Comment: @DenysPrykhodko => added `pyspark` version. Please check and if satisfies your requirement, please accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should .map your dataset instead of reducing because the count of rows in your example are same as in source dataset,  inside map you could reduce values as python list

Answer (score 0):

use **mapValues()** + **itertools.groupby()**:

```
from itertools import groupby

data.mapValues(lambda x: [ (k, sum(f[1] for f in g)) for (k,g) in groupby(sorted(x), key=lambda d: d[0]) ]) \
    .collect()
#[(1, [('k1', 6), ('k2', 3)]), (2, [('k1', 6), ('k3', 9)])]
```

with *itertools.groupby*, we use the first item of the tuple as grouped-key `k` and sum the 2nd item from the tuple in each `g`.

**Edit:** for a large data set, sorting with itertools.groupby is expensive, just write up a function w/o sorting to handle the same:

```
def merge_tuples(x):
    d = {}
    for (k,v) in x: 
        d[k] = d.get(k,0) + v
    return d.items()

data.mapValues(merge_tuples).collect()
#[(1, [('k2', 3), ('k1', 6)]), (2, [('k3', 9), ('k1', 6)])]
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks to be very straightforward and works for me, but on a very large dataset (deepest list of (key,val)) I understand the itertools wouldn't make use of distributed cores and might be very slow?

Comment: @DenysPrykhodko, sorting can be expensive for a very large set, this is not necessary anyway for this task. you can check the updated function which uses dictionary only w/o sorting the data.